# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined

Tags: typescript, object, typeerror

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
interface VehicleSeatData {
    index: number;
    positions: Vector3Mp;
}

interface VehicleSeat {
    [key: string]: VehicleSeatData;
}

getSeatData(vehicle: VehicleMp): VehicleSeat | null {
        if(!vehicle) {
            return null; 
        }

        let seats: VehicleSeat = {};

        seats['seat_r'].index = vehicle.getBoneIndexByName('seat_r');
        seats['seat_pside_f'].index = vehicle.getBoneIndexByName('seat_pside_f');

        seats['seat_r'].positions = vehicle.getWorldPositionOfBone(seats['seat_r'].index);
        seats['seat_pside_f'].positions = vehicle.getWorldPositionOfBone(seats['seat_pside_f'].index);

        return seats;
    }
```

Error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, everything I've read (so far) tells me I'm in the right direction. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `seats` as an empty object.
`let seats = {}`.
Then you access `seats.seat_r` (same as `seats['seat_r']`) which defaults to `undefined`. Afterwards you attempt to access its `index` property, which does not exist (`undefined.index` -> `property 'index' of undefined`).

In order to solve this, you will have to set each property of `seats` to an empty version of type `VehicleSeatData`.

```
  let seats: VehicleSeat = {
    'seat_r': {
      index: undefined,
      positions: undefined,
    },
    'seat_pside_f': {
      index: undefined,
      positions: undefined,
    },
    'seat_r': {
      index: undefined,
      positions: undefined,
    },
    'seat_pside_f': {
      index: undefined,
      positions: undefined,
    },
  };
  
  // It is also enough to just initialize the properties as an empty object:
  // let seats: VehicleSeat = {
  //   'seat_r': {},
  //   'seat_pside_f': {},
  //   'seat_r': {},
  //   'seat_pside_f': {},
  // };
  

  // Now you can access the properties and set its sub-properties.
  seats['seat_r'].index = vehicle.getBoneIndexByName('seat_r');
  seats['seat_pside_f'].index = vehicle.getBoneIndexByName('seat_pside_f');

  seats['seat_r'].positions = vehicle.getWorldPositionOfBone(seats['seat_r'].index);
  seats['seat_pside_f'].positions = vehicle.getWorldPositionOfBone(seats['seat_pside_f'].index);
```

This also means you might have to change your type of

```
interface VehicleSeatData {
  index: number;
  positions: Vector3Mp;
}
```

to

```
interface VehicleSeatData {
  index?: number;
  positions?: Vector3Mp;
}
```

because the properties are, in this example, possibly undefined until you correctly set them.

Comment: Is there any case where I wouldn't have to set their properties first before using it? I was hoping I could set them dynamically

Answer (score -1):

VehicleSeatData does not have any property seat_r, try below code.

```
seats = {
seat_r:{
    index: vehicle.getBoneIndexByName('seat_r');
    positions: Vector3Mp;
}
```

}